# Select by Attribute - Field and Values Expressions

Tags: qgis

Please see below image for reference.  Attempting to select multiple values within the Criteria_1 field but this is not working.  Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
"Criteria_1" in ('Best', 'High', 'Medium', etc...)
```

Comment: That worked beautifully.  Thank you.